# How to get a specific chart from a sheet and paste it on another sheet, in a specific range using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, charts

Problem:
I got 06 charts in a sheet. So the script does the following:

It iterates over a list of tickers from Sheet named List.

It pastes each ticker being iterated in cell A3 of sheet template

Copies one of the charts from sheet named template

Pastes it in cell E5 of sheet List

The script below runs up to the last line and then I got the following error:
TypeError: ss.getRange(...).insertChart is not a function

Here's the script, I'm using:

```
function updateTickers() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List");
  var tickerRng = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var allSharesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template");
  var startRow = 2;

  for (var a = 0; a < tickerRng.length; a++) {
    var ticker = tickerRng[a][0];
    if (ticker == 'nndm') {
      if (ticker[0] != '') {
        var setRow = parseInt(a) + startRow;
        allSharesSheet.getRange("a3").setValue(ticker);
        var chart1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(ticker).getCharts()[0];
        ss.getRange(setRow, 5).insertChart(chart1); //This is where the error pops up.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The method of `insertChart()` is for Class Sheet. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart) But in your script, this method is used for Class Range. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this. But I cannot understand about `I got 06 charts in a sheet. So the script gets that sheet updated, copies one of the charts and pastes in another sheet, in cell E5.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike! This is exactly the intent!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `This is exactly the intent!`, I cannot still understand about `I got 06 charts in a sheet. So the script gets that sheet updated, copies one of the charts and pastes in another sheet, in cell E5.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Just added the steps to the question above, @Tanaike ! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. From your updated question, I proposed a modification points as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize. At that time, in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike! Thank you for your suggestion. I've stumbled upon another challenge and will get back to this one, once I got the other figured out. I'll confirm it, once this is implemented and tested. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your situation. I would like to wait for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy a chart in the sheet of `ticker` to the sheet "List".
- You want to move the copied sheet to the cell "E5".

  - In your script, it seems that you want to move the copied sheet to `getRange(setRow, 5)`. This answer follows to this.

#### Modification points:

- The method of insertChart() is for Class Sheet. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart) But in your script, this method is used for Class Range. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this.

  - I have already mentioned this at my comment.
- In order to move the position of chart, it is required to update the chart.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
ss.getRange(setRow, 5).insertChart(chart1); //This is where the error pops up.
```

To:

```
ss.insertChart(chart1.modify().setPosition(setRow, 5, 0, 0).build());
```

or, you want to put the chart to the cell "E5", please use the following script.

```
ss.insertChart(chart1.modify().setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0).build());
```

#### References:

- [insertChart(chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart)
- [modify()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#modify)

Comment: Hello, Tanaike! Appreciate your huge help. I now get the following error: Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id XXXXXXXXXXX and it points to the following line in the code: ```      allSharesSheet.insertChart(chart1.modify().setPosition(activeCell,9,0,0).build());```

Comment: @Antonio Santos Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my experience, when I had the same error, I could resolve the error by recreating the chart. If in your situation, this was not the direct solution, I apologize again.